# Laravel error message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Does anyone have any idea what this error message relates to and how I can resolve it;

`file_put_contents(/var/www/myproject/bootstrap/cache/services.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

This happens very often, sometimes when I add a new provider or when I run `composer update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **nzt** has stated it is a permissions issue.

So if you had originally set the permission correctly on that directory and have this issue, more than likely the reason for this is when you run those CLI commands (artisan, composer) you are running them as a different user than the web server uses. If that file gets recreated after you have ran one of those, it wont have the correct permissions for the web server to write to it any more.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the web server or PHP-FPM user has write access to the `bootstrap/cache` folder:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1

> Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server.